# Change text of smjobbless dialog kAuthorizationEnvironmentPrompt

Tags: objective-c, authorization

SMJobBless has a dialog prompt that tells the user it is installing a helper tool and to type password to proceed. I would like to change the text.

Instead of changing the text, the following code puts my custom text at the beginning and still displays the default text. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
// Creating auth item to bless helper tool and install framework
AuthorizationItem authItem = {kSMRightBlessPrivilegedHelper, 0, NULL, 0};

// Creating a set of authorization rights
AuthorizationRights authRights = {1, &authItem};

NSString *promptText = @"Customized Text. Privilege?\n\n";

AuthorizationItem dialogConfiguration[1] = { kAuthorizationEnvironmentPrompt, [promptText length], (char *) [promptText UTF8String], 0 };

AuthorizationEnvironment authorizationEnvironment = { 0 };
authorizationEnvironment.items = dialogConfiguration;
authorizationEnvironment.count = 1;

// Specifying authorization options for authorization
AuthorizationFlags flags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed | kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

// Open dialog and prompt user for password
OSStatus status = AuthorizationCreate(&authRights, &authorizationEnvironment, flags, authRef);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use kAuthorizationRightExecute instead of kSMRightBlessPrivilegedHelper will get a short text which only ask for input password.. and use kAuthorizationEnvironmentPrompt as environment can add additional text in the beginning of tips..